# Is it possible to use Mockito in Kotlin?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, kotlin

The problem I'm facing is that `Matchers.anyObject()` returns `null`. When used to mock method that only accepts non-nullable types it causes a "Should not be null" exception to be thrown.

```
`when`(mockedBackend.login(anyObject())).thenAnswer { invocationOnMock -> someResponse }
```

Mocked method:

```
public open fun login(userCredentials: UserCredentials): Response
```

Comment: There's a discussion on a kotlin community site on how to avoid this problem, check it out: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/443551

Comment: Thank you. Seems like devnet.jetbrains.com is not very well indexed by google.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There are two possible workarounds:

```
private fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}

private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T

@Test
fun myTest() {
    `when`(mockedBackend).login(anyObject())).thenAnswer { ... }
}
```

The other workaround is

```
private fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
}

@Test
fun myTest() {
    `when`(mockedBackend).login(anyObject())).thenAnswer { ... }
}
```

Here is [some more discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-use-mockito-with-kotlin/324) on this topic, where the workaround is first suggested.

Comment: I believe SO kindly asks that you replicate the content of the link in your answer as well, so that if the link ever goes dead this answer is still useful.

Comment: Sadly, in 1.0.0-beta-4584 this workaround doesn't seem to work anymore: `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type X`.

Comment: @nhaarman works perfect for me, could you please point me to the exact case?

Comment: its not working on Kotlin 1.2.40. isnt there any other workaround ?

Comment: @nhaarman Kotlin 1.3.11, Mockito 2.7.12, Kotlin Mockito 1.5.0, Jan 2019: Workaround 1... well, it works around. My use case is within the given/when clause.

Comment: Mockito.anyObject is marked as deprecated and will be removed in Mockito 3.0 FYI

Comment: anyObject has been removed. This answer no longer works in newer versions of Mockito, FYI to readers. Keep looking. :(

Answer (score 53):

For those who need typed `any(type: Class<T>)`

```
    private fun <T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any<T>(type)
```

This would work and the type check also happens!

Comment: Is possible to avoid passing the *ClassName::class.java* in argument using the reified args:
`inline fun <reified T> anyNonNull(): T = Mockito.any<T>(T::class.java)`

Comment: Perfect, it doesn't work

Answer (score 40):

You can use the following helper functions to use Mockito's any(), eq() and capture() matchers in Kotlin:

```
/**
 * Returns Mockito.eq() as nullable type to avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException when
 * null is returned.
 *
 * Generic T is nullable because implicitly bounded by Any?.
 */
fun <T> eq(obj: T): T = Mockito.eq<T>(obj)

/**
 * Returns Mockito.any() as nullable type to avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException when
 * null is returned.
 */
fun <T> any(): T = Mockito.any<T>()

/**
 * Returns ArgumentCaptor.capture() as nullable type to avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException
 * when null is returned.
 */
fun <T> capture(argumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<T>): T = argumentCaptor.capture()
```

See [MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt) from the Android Architecture Blueprints repository by Google.

Comment: Looks like the URL is moved to: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt

Comment: Great thanks! Works with latest version of Mockito as well (v3.3.3) and Kotlin (v1.3.72)

Answer (score 11):

I use `verify` a lot to make sure the parameters passed to a function are also correct.

To do this, and still avoid the NPE you can use kotlin's elvis operator.
for example:
`verify(mock).func(same(my_obj) ?: my_obj)`

This way, mockito is satisfied because it actually verifies the variable, and kotlin is satisfied because we pass a non null object.

Another thing I stumbled upon was the mockito-kotlin library which solves exactly this issue
https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin

Answer (score 2):

it just need to return a nonnull result when you use `Mockito.any()`;

```
Mockito.any() ?: 0
Mockito.any() ?: HashMap<Int,Int>()
Mockito.any() ?: {}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

To extend on the answer provided by @makovkastar, you can provide a nullable or non-nullable Matcher like this:

```
/**
 * Matcher that returns null
 */
private inline fun <reified T> any(): T = Mockito.any<T>()

/**
 * Matcher never returns null
 */
private inline fun <reified T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any(type)
```

Comment: For me `private fun <T> any(): T = Mockito.any()` is also working.