# kotlin and ArgumentCaptor - IllegalStateException

Tags: android, robolectric, kotlin

I have a problem with capturing the Class argument via ArgumentCaptor. My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = intArrayOf(21), constants = BuildConfig::class)
class MyViewModelTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var activityHandlerMock: IActivityHandler;

    @Captor
    lateinit var classCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Class<BaseActivity>>

    @Captor
    lateinit var booleanCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Boolean>

    private var objectUnderTest: MyViewModel? = null

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        initMocks(this)
        ...
        objectUnderTest = MyViewModel(...)
    }

    @Test
    fun thatNavigatesToAddListScreenOnAddClicked(){
        //given

        //when
        objectUnderTest?.addNewList()

        //then
        verify(activityHandlerMock).navigateTo(classCaptor.capture(), booleanCaptor.capture())
        var clazz = classCaptor.value
        assertNotNull(clazz);
        assertFalse(booleanCaptor.value);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, following exception is thrown:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: classCaptor.capture() must not be null
Is it possible to use argument captors in kotlin?

=========
UPDATE 1:
Kotlin: 1.0.0-beta-4584
Mockito: 1.10.19
Robolectric: 3.0

=========
UPDATE 2:
 Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: classCaptor.capture() must not be null

at com.example.view.model.ShoplistsViewModelTest.thatNavigatesToAddListScreenOnAddClicked(ShoplistsViewModelTest.kt:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Just tried [your example](https://gist.github.com/miensol/d2a3c070f9efc50d8d2f) and it works just fine. What are versions of kotlin, mockito and roboelectric that you're using?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have updated the question. Which versions did you try?

Comment: Just rechecked [the sample from gist](https://gist.github.com/miensol/d2a3c070f9efc50d8d2f) and it works fine with the versions you've listed. Seems that your code must be somewhat different. Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: I've added the stacktrace. Unfortunately it doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: You're right it does not. It seems strange though that you have `RobolectricTestRunner` in stack trace even though the `RunWith` says `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`

Comment: Could the problem be that the return value of classCaptor.capture() is null?  Kotlin then thinks that the signature of IActivityHandler#navigateTo(Class, Boolean) cannot allow a null argument?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You are right. I didn't notice that the navigateTo method accepts only non-null values. When I changed singature of navigateTo method to this one:  fun navigateTo(clazz: Class<out BaseActivity>?, closeCurrent: Boolean), then example works fine. If you want, please, add an answer to this question, so in case anyone else has the same problem he can find the solution.

Comment: @MBuhot See Ramps's comment about posting an answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The return value of `classCaptor.capture()` is null, but the signature of `IActivityHandler#navigateTo(Class, Boolean)` does not allow a null argument.

The [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library provides supporting functions to solve this problem.

Code should be:

```
    @Captor
    lateinit var classCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Class<BaseActivity>>

    @Captor
    lateinit var booleanCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Boolean>

    ...

    @Test
    fun thatNavigatesToAddListScreenOnAddClicked(){
        //given

        //when
        objectUnderTest?.addNewList()

        //then
        verify(activityHandlerMock).navigateTo(
com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.capture<Class<BaseActivity>>(classCaptor.capture()), 
com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.capture<Boolean>(booleanCaptor.capture())
)
        var clazzValue = classCaptor.value
        assertNotNull(clazzValue);
        val booleanValue = booleanCaptor.value
        assertFalse(booleanValue);
    }
```

OR

```
var classCaptor = com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.argumentCaptor<Class<BaseActivity>>()
var booleanCaptor = com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.argumentCaptor<Boolean>()
...
 verify(activityHandlerMock).navigateTo(
classCaptor.capture(), 
booleanCaptor.capture()
)
```

also in build.gradle add this:

```
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
```

Comment: Just adding to the above answer for anyone else searching for this: What you need is com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.capture(classCaptor) instead of classCaptor.capture()

Comment: And [here](https://gist.github.com/spookyUnknownUser/f0ab1d3b9a99a87c0c0e0155abac81c9) is how a Test from google codelabs would look with the argument Captor

Comment: I tried many times to apply com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.capture but couldn't success. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715702/mockito-argumentcaptor-for-kotlin-function. There is a link to a wiki: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-captors. So, I tried to remove several Mockito* libraries from import, change `verify` to com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify, a problem disappeared.

Comment: I had to explicitly specify that the T type should not be null : `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.capture<MyType>(argumentCaptor)`

Comment: @CoolMind that was helpful. Thanks. For everyone else, please [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268842/1276636) which states what to do explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for this... phew! Despite all the features in Kotlin I started to dislike it... it's so unreadable and the codes are basically like encrypted

Answer (score 71):

From this [blog](http://derekwilson.net/blog/2018/08/23/mokito-kotlin)

"Getting matchers to work with Kotlin can be a problem. If you have a method written in kotlin that does not take a nullable parameter then we cannot match with it using Mockito.any(). This is because it can return void and this is not assignable to a non-nullable parameter. If the method being matched is written in Java then I think that it will work as all Java objects are implicitly nullable."

A wrapper function is needed that returns `ArgumentCaptor.capture()` as nullable type.

Add the following as a helper method to your test

```
fun <T> capture(argumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<T>): T = argumentCaptor.capture()
```

Please see, [MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/observability/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt) provided by Google in the Android Architecture repo for reference. the `capture` function provides a convenient way to call `ArgumentCaptor.capture()`. Call

```
verify(activityHandlerMock).navigateTo(capture(classCaptor), capture(booleanCaptor))
```

**Update:** If the above solution does not work for you, please check Roberto Leinardi's solution in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks, it works fo me. The part of GoogleSample about UnitTest is well worth leanrning!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, angryd. Sure!, I basically refer to their sample whenever I get stuck and it's also well documented.

Comment: I think  this should be the accepted answer. Using fun capture(captor: ArgumentCaptor<T>) helped me without having to add mockito-kotlin:

Comment: Sure, @Kaskasi. It's way simpler to use. Thanks.

Comment: I am still having the same issue after adding:
`fun <T> capture(argumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<T>): T = argumentCaptor.capture()`  

Then in the test:
`val userCacheCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User::class.java)
    Mockito.verify(userCache, Mockito.times(1)).set(Mockito.anyString(), capture(userCacheCaptor))`

the error is: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: capture(userCacheCaptor) must not be null
`

Comment: @vlio20, how about casting the userCacheCaptor to the User class? More like: `Mockito.verify(eq(userCache), Mockito.times(1)).set(Mockito.anyString(), capture(userCacheCaptor) as User)`. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @IkechukwuKalu I had the same issue than I solved using the annotation `@Captor private lateinit var snackbarManagerArgumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<ShowSnackbarEvent>` and then the helper `verify(snackbarManager).show(capture(snackbarManagerArgumentCaptor))`.

Comment: The solution @RobertoLeinardi suggested worked for me.

Comment: Works for me. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This was so helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 20):

Use kotlin-mockito https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/1.5.0 as dependency and sample code as written below :

```
argumentCaptor<Hotel>().apply {
    verify(hotelSaveService).save(capture())

    assertThat(allValues.size).isEqualTo(1)
    assertThat(firstValue.name).isEqualTo("İstanbul Hotel")
    assertThat(firstValue.totalRoomCount).isEqualTo(10000L)
    assertThat(firstValue.freeRoomCount).isEqualTo(5000L)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As stated by [CoolMind in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773958/kotlin-and-argumentcaptor-illegalstateexception#comment87994136_35100208), you first need to add gradle import for [Kotlin-Mockito](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and then shift all your imports to use this library. Your imports will now look like:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.argumentCaptor
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.any
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.eq
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.isNull
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.verify
```

Then your test class will be something like this:

```
val mArgumentCaptor = argumentCaptor<SignUpInteractor.Callback>()

@Test
fun signUp_success() {
    val customer = Customer().apply {
        name = "Test Name"
        email = "test@example.com"
        phone = "0123444456789"
        phoneDdi = "+92"
        phoneNumber = ""
        countryCode = "92"
        password = "123456"
    }
    mPresenter.signUp(customer)
    verify(mView).showProgress()
    verify(mInteractor).createAccount(any(), isNull(), mArgumentCaptor.capture())
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305217/is-it-possible-to-use-mockito-in-kotlin) my solution here:

```
fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T

//open verificator
val verificator = verify(activityHandlerMock)

//capture (would be same with all matchers)
classCaptor.capture()
booleanCaptor.capture()

//hack
verificator.navigateTo(uninitialized(), uninitialized())
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but this is the only solution that has worked for me so far. Although technically, the others should work as well, as all they seem to do is a generic cast of null to T.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the fine solutions presented worked for you, here is one more way to try. It's based on [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying).

```
[app/build.gradle]
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0'
}
```

Define `Rule` and `Mock` in your test file.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MockitoTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockList: MutableList<String>
```

And here is an example.

```
    @Test
    fun `argument captor`() {
        mockList.add("one")
        mockList.add("two")

        argumentCaptor<String>().apply {
            // Verify that "add()" is called twice, and capture the arguments.
            verify(mockList, times(2)).add(capture())

            assertEquals(2, allValues.size)
            assertEquals("one", firstValue)
            assertEquals("two", secondValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `@Captor` as well.

```
@Captor
private lateinit var argumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<String>

@Test
fun `argument captor`() {
    mockList.add("one")
    mockList.add("two")

    verify(mockList, times(2)).add(capture(argumentCaptor))

    assertEquals(2, argumentCaptor.allValues.size)
    assertEquals("one", argumentCaptor.firstValue)
    assertEquals("two", argumentCaptor.secondValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here after the kotlin-Mockito library didn't help. 
I created a solution using reflection.
It is a function which extracts the argument provided to the mocked-object earlier:

```
fun <T: Any, S> getTheArgOfUsedFunctionInMockObject(mockedObject: Any, function: (T) -> S, clsOfArgument: Class<T>): T{
    val argCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(clsOfArgument)
    val ver = verify(mockedObject)
    argCaptor.capture()
    ver.javaClass.methods.first { it.name == function.reflect()!!.name }.invoke(ver, uninitialized())
    return argCaptor.value
}
private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

Usage:
(Say I have mocked my repository and tested a viewModel. After calling the viewModel's "update()" method with a MenuObject object, I want to make sure that the MenuObject actually called upon the repository's "updateMenuObject()" method:

```
viewModel.update(menuObjectToUpdate)
val arg = getTheArgOfUsedFunctionInMockObject(mockedRepo, mockedRepo::updateMenuObject, MenuObject::class.java)
assertEquals(menuObjectToUpdate, arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper over argument captor

```
class CaptorWrapper<T:Any>(private val captor:ArgumentCaptor<T>, private val obj:T){
    fun capture():T{
        captor.capture()
        return obj
    }

    fun captor():ArgumentCaptor<T>{
        return captor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
/**
 * Use instead of ArgumentMatcher.argThat(matcher: ArgumentMatcher<T>)
 */
fun <T> safeArgThat(matcher: ArgumentMatcher<T>): T {
    ThreadSafeMockingProgress.mockingProgress().argumentMatcherStorage
        .reportMatcher(matcher)
    return uninitialized()
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

**Usage:**

```
verify(spiedElement, times(1)).method(
    safeArgThat(
        CustomMatcher()
    )
)
```