# Mockito ArgumentCaptor for Kotlin function

Tags: mockito, kotlin

Consider a function that takes an interface implementation as an argument like this:

```
interface Callback {
    fun done()
}

class SomeClass {        

    fun doSomeThing(callback: Callback) {

        // do something

        callback.done()

    }    
}
```

When I want to test the caller of this function, I can do something like

```
val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Callback::class)
Mockito.verify(someClass).doSomeThing(captor.capture())
```

To test what the other class does when the callback is invoked, I can then do

```
captor.value.done()
```

**Question:** How can I do the same if I replace the callback interface with a high order function like

```
fun doSomeThing(done: () -> Unit) {

    // do something

    done.invoke()

}
```

Can this be done with ArgumentCaptor and what class do I have to use in `ArgumentCaptor.forClass(???)`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I recommend [nhaarman/mockito-kotlin: Using Mockito with Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)

It solves this through an [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) with a [reified type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters):

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> argumentCaptor() = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(T::class.java)
```

Source: [mockito-kotlin/ArgumentCaptor.kt at a6f860461233ba92c7730dd42b0faf9ba2ce9281 · nhaarman/mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/a6f860461233ba92c7730dd42b0faf9ba2ce9281/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/ArgumentCaptor.kt#L30)

e.g.:

```
val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>()
verify(someClass).doSomeThing(captor.capture())
```

or

```
val captor: () -> Unit = argumentCaptor()
verify(someClass).doSomeThing(captor.capture())
```

Comment: I already have this library included in my project, could you provide an example how to use the ArgumentCaptor to invoke a function that was passed to a mock?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: I am getting captor.capture() must not be null :(

Comment: @JesusAlmaral You can create a new question on this site with appropriate labels, code samples, etc. to get help showing what you've tried and what error messages you are getting, etc.

Comment: Thanks @mfulton26, I just posted a question with what I tried here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945675/mocktito-argumentcaptor-for-kotlin-lambda-with-arguments

Comment: The wiki from mockito-kotlin has some interesting syntax for using captors: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-captors

Comment: @JesusAlmaral you must be using the mockito-kotlin doesnt give that error. You are getting the error because the captor.capture() returns null. Copy code from library source. Or else you have to handle non-null types in kotlin,

Comment: @asco, After you get the reference by val 'func = allValues[0]', you should write 'func()' and the function will be invoked

Comment: I have the same code but strangely the compilation error says that the method doesn't match any of the existing implementation. I'm trying to capture the request from `restTemplate` as bellow: `val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> HttpEntity<String>>()` and
`Mockito.verify(restTemplate).exchange("testUrl", HttpMethod.POST, captor.capture(), String::class.java)` 
Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I tried what @mfulton26 suggested, but was getting an error message saying `captor.capture() must not be null`. and this was what worked for me.

Declared a member variable `captor` with `@Captor` annotation,

```
@Captor private lateinit var captor: ArgumentCaptor<Callback>
```

and in my @Test,

```
verify(someClass).doSomething(capture(captor))
```

Comment: This returns `java.lang.IllegalStateException: callbackCaptor.capture() must not be null`

Comment: To deal with must not be null issue                                                                       object MockitoHelper {
  fun <T> capture(argumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<T>): T = argumentCaptor.capture()
}                                                                                                                                  
 for complete ref check this link  http://derekwilson.net/blog/2018/10/19/mockito-kotlin-2

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem just now and solved it with an inline `argumentCaptor` from `mockito-kotlin`:

```
argumentCaptor<String>().apply {
  verify(myClass, times(2)).setItems(capture())

  assertEquals(2, allValues.size)
  assertEquals("test", firstValue)
}
```

`firstValue` is a reference to the first captured object.

Source: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-captors

Answer (score 2):

Based on `mfulton26`'s answer, i create an example below.

to show **how to invoke the captured function or lambda expression**.

you need the [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin)

---

Assume we have a Class A, it has a suspend function with two higher order function as parameters.

how can we mock the `onSuccess` scenario and `onError` scenario

```kotlin
class A {
    suspend fun methodB(onSuccess: (ModelA) -> Unit, onError: (ErrorA) -> Unit)
}
```

Here is the dummy example

```kotlin
// in the unit test class

private val mockClassA = // use annotation or mock()

// decalre the higer oder function capture variables.
private val onSuccessCapture = argumentCaptor<(ModelA) -> Unit>()
private val onErrorCapture = argumentCaptor<(ErrorA) -> Unit>()


@Test
fun testMethodB = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {

   doAnswer {
       // on success scenario 
       val modelA = // get ModelA
       onSuccessCapture.firstValue.invoke(modelA) // this line will let the onSuccess parameter been called

       // on error scenario
       // val errorA = // get ErrorA
       //onErrorCapture.firstValue.invoke(errorA)

   }.`when`(mockClassA).methodB(onSuccessCapture.capture(), onErrorCapture.capture())
   
}
```