# Mocktito ArgumentCaptor for Kotlin lambda with arguments

Tags: android, function, lambda, mockito, kotlin

I am trying to test this on Kotlin:

```
verify(myInterface).doSomething(argumentCaptor.capture())
capture.value.invoke(0L)
```

Where doSomething is:

```
doSomething((Long) -> Unit)
```

How can I create an ArgumentCaptor for this? Right now I am doing this

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> argumentCaptor() = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(T::class.java)!!
    val captor = argumentCaptor<(Long) -> Unit>()

    verify(mainApiInterface!!).downloadUserProfilePicture(captor.capture())
    captor.value.invoke(0L)
```

But I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: captor.capture() must not be null

I also tried integrating mockito-kotlin but I get a PowerMockito error:

> No instance field named "reported" could be found in the class hierarchy of org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.

Comment: And just for the record: the things that PowerMock does to byte code can give one a headache when working pure java. I would really stay away from using PowerMockito with bytecode generated by anything else but javac.

Answer (score 2):

Using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying) like this seems to work:

```
    val myService = mock<MyInterface>()

    myService.doSomething {
        println(it)
    }

    verify(myService).doSomething(capture { function ->
        function.invoke(123)
    })
```

Edit: removed unnecessary `argumentCaptor<(Long) -> Unit>().apply {}` - it wasn't used

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but the thing is I have conflicts with PowerMock because of what I wrote above, I am using PowerMock because I am working with some static classes

Comment: Haha you're on your own then - there be dragons!

Comment: What I missed? `capture(ArgumentCaptor<T>)` has parameter not lambda.

Comment: If you are not using mockito-kotlin, check the solution on this page, which fixed it for me :) http://derekwilson.net/blog/2018/10/19/mockito-kotlin-2

Answer (score 2):

as with kotlin 1.3.72 and com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0 the following works fine for me:

create an argument captor via `val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>()` and call `captor.capture()` on it.

There's also a variant for nullable captors with `nullableArgumentCaptor()`

The following unit-test captures the lambda of type `() -> Unit` that is given to `diff.open()`. To capture it at runtime it then uses `captor.capture()`

```
    // given
    val onClose = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>()
    // when
    diff.open(file, serialized) { onDiffClosed(clusterResource, documentBeforeDiff) }
    // then
    verify(diff).open(any(), any(), onClose.capture())
```

The nhaarman wrapper for mockito creates a wrapper `KArgumentCaptor` for the mockito class `ArgumentCaptor`. The nhaarman wrapper fixes your error by creating an instance instead of `null` as in mockito.