# ArgumentCaptor with @Captor annotation in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm using an [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) with [@Captor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/Captor.html) annotation in Kotlin like this

```
@Captor private lateinit var captor: ArgumentCaptor<MyObject>
@Mock private lateinit var mockObject: InnerObject
private lateinit var objectToTest: MyClass

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    objectToTest = MyClass(mockObject)
}

fun testSomething() {
    objectToTest.doSomething()

    verify(mockObject).callMethod(captor.capture())
    assertThat(expectedResult, captor.value)

}
```

The method callMethod() is called inside doSomething() and I want to capture the parameter sent to it.

My problem is that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: captor.capture() must not be null
```

I tried the same approach using java and it's working, when I convert it to Kotlin I get the exception.

Is this related to Kotlin? Or am I not using @Captor the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related to Kotlin, because all parameters and fields are not nullable by default. You have to define the parameter of callMethod nullable:

```
mockObject).callMethod( any : Any? )
```

Another way to solve it, is to use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) which avoids such IllegalStateException and @KCaptor annotation of [mockito4kotlin.annotation](https://github.com/wickie73/mockito4kotlin.annotation):

```
import org.mockito4kotlin.annotation.KCaptor
import org.mockito4kotlin.annotation.MockAnnotations

@KCaptor
lateinit var captor: KArgumentCaptor<MyObject>

fun setUp() {
    MockAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    objectToTest = MyClass(mockObject)
}

fun testSomething() {

    objectToTest.doSomething()


    verify(mockObject).callMethod(captor.capture())
    assertThat(expectedResult, captor.value)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Mockito, you need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in test class `setup` method. Your captor property was never initialized, that's why you are getting IllegalStateException.

**Edit**: 
I think that you'll find a solution in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773958/kotlin-and-argumentcaptor-illegalstateexception). 
Your question might also be a duplicate question since the similar problem is stated in the link that I provided you.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm doing initialisation. I updated the post with my more code