# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getCallbackCaptor.capture() must not be null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

captor value return null. Using ArgumentCaptor for the parameter in the method for unit test, but it returns null

```
@Captor
    private lateinit var getCallbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<DataSource.GetCallback<Response>>

@Before init(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
 videoViewModel = VideoViewModel(remoteRepository)
}

@Test test1(){

 videoViewModel.setUpConference(conferenceToken)

 verify<Repository>(remoteRepository).setUpConferenceRequest(
                conferenceToken,
                getCallbackCaptor.capture()
            )


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you define the behaviour for the mock, when `setUpConferenceRequest` is called? Consider providing a [mre] that includes the definition of `remoteRepository` as well as the class under test.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: I think your problem is caused by kotlin, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773958/kotlin-and-argumentcaptor-illegalstateexception