# Kotlin: Manually inlining a generic function produce a different result?

Tags: generics, mockito, kotlin

I have a simple test class

```
class SimpleClassTest {

    private fun <T> anyObject(): T {
        return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    }

    lateinit var simpleObject: SimpleClass
    @Mock lateinit var injectedObject: InjectedClass


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSimpleFunction() {
        simpleObject = SimpleClass(injectedObject)
        simpleObject.simpleFunction()

        verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(anyObject())
    }
}
```

It works fine and pass.

Since the private generic `anyObject()` function is only used once, so I decide to inlining it (manually) i.e. remove the need of that function, whereby I change from

```
verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(anyObject())
```

to

```
verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(Mockito.anyObject<DependentClass>())
```

However this now error as 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.anyObject<DependentClass>() must not be null`

Anything I did wrong inlining the function call to a direct statement?

Is there anything different between using

```
private fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    return Mockito.anyObject<T>()
}
```

and the below?

```
Mockito.anyObject<DependentClass>()
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin and its plugin are you using?

Comment: I use 1.0.1-2. And when I switch to 1.0.2, it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source for `Mockito.anyObject()`:

```
/**
 * Matches anything, including null.
 * <p>
 * This is an alias of: {@link #any()} and {@link #any(java.lang.Class)}
 * <p>
 * See examples in javadoc for {@link Matchers} class
 * 
 * @return <code>null</code>.
 */
public static <T> T anyObject() {
    return (T) reportMatcher(Any.ANY).returnNull();
}
```

This method sets some internal state for Mockito, and then proceeds to return `null`. Since you're expecting a non-null instance in your `settingDependentObject()` method, the runtime fails.

---

Why your first method succeeded, however, I'm not sure. Casting `null` to `T` [seemed to work a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305217/is-it-possible-to-use-mockito-in-kotlin/35776132#35776132), but it doesn't work for me anymore. For that matter, I can't get your first implementation to succeed either.

Comment: To overcome this problem, I wrote a little [helper library](https://www.github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin).

Comment: Hi @nhaarman, great to hear from you. Actually I'm aware of the null error issue due to Kotlin null-safe requirement, and Mockito returning null, and were wondering how that function got it working for me. Hence I post my question up as it is. I did try to use the helper library, but there's an issue when using a OkHttp response. I post the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380830/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-when-using-kotlin-mokito-library, which is specifically for you. (I think others will not be able to answer it, as it might be your library specific). Thanks

Comment: @nhaarman The first method works because the compiler doesn't insert a null check after calling  `SimpleClassTest.anyObject` function. This behavior may be changed later, see [KT-8135](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8135)

Comment: @llya, thanks for pointing this out. Perhaps you could put the comment as answer, explaining why one compiles and the other doesn't, that I could give a tick to it. As I plan to tick answer that covers both scenario.