# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using Kotlin-Mokito library

Tags: mockito, kotlin

any() from Kotlin Mockito library crash with the following code

**The Test Class**

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.any
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class SimpleClassTest {

    lateinit var simpleObject: SimpleClass
    @Mock lateinit var injectedObject: InjectedClass


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSimpleFunction() {
        simpleObject = SimpleClass(injectedObject)
        simpleObject.simpleFunction()

        verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(any())

    }
}
```

**The Source Class**

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.Protocol
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response


class SimpleClass(val injectedClass: InjectedClass) {

    fun simpleFunction() {
        injectedClass.settingDependentObject(Response.Builder()
                .request(Request.Builder().url("https://example.com").build())
                .code(200)
                .body(null)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .build())
    }
}

open class DependentClass(response: Response) {

}

open class InjectedClass() {
    lateinit var response: Response

    open fun settingDependentObject(response: Response) {
        this.response = response
    }
}
```

The Crash Log

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$Constructor.call(FunctionCaller.kt:63)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl$DefaultImpls.call(KCallableImpl.kt:67)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.call(KFunctionImpl.kt:30)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl$DefaultImpls.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:103)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.callBy(KFunctionImpl.kt:30)
    at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.CreateInstanceKt.newInstance(CreateInstance.kt:138)
    at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.CreateInstanceKt.createInstance(CreateInstance.kt:60)
    at com.elyeproj.phoneinfo.SimpleClassTest.testSimpleFunction(SimpleClassTest.kt:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Response.<init>(Response.java:56)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: There is an [open PR](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/pull/23) that solves [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/20) [issue](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/17). However, I'm not entirely sure if this is production worthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library relies on the reflection to instantiate an object of a given type to be used as mockito "Any" object. 
It might not be possible for those classes which have non-trivial constructors.  `Response` is one of them.

If you could get an instance of `Response` somehow, you can use it instead like:

```
verify(injectedObject).settingDependentObject(Mockito.any<Response>() ?: someResponse)
```

Comment: Ya, that's the issue. Hope nharmaan could think of a way to resolve this issue in his library.

Comment: `Mockito.any<Response>()` will always return `null`, won't it?

Comment: @miensol, yes, that's why an elvis operator with some non-null response is required after

Comment: @Ilya so it's equivalent to `null ?: someResponse`  which in turn is equivalent to just `someResponse`, isn't it?

Comment: @miensol, not it isn't, because `Mockito.any` is a function with a side-effect, it modifies the internal state that is used then by the object being mocked.