# Kotlin and EasyMock null problems

Tags: kotlin, easymock

I'm having some trouble making Kotlin and EasyMock play nice with each other.

I have a test containing something like this:

```
expect(foo.createClassLoader(aryEq(arrayOf("foo.jar")))).andReturn(classLoader)
```

(where `foo` is a mock object)

However, this throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: aryEq(arrayOf("foo.jar")) must not be null` because my `createClassLoader` method doesn't accept a nullable array, and for some reason `EasyMock.aryEq` returns null:

```
public static <T> T[] aryEq(final T[] value) {
    reportMatcher(new ArrayEquals(value));
    return null;
}
```

Is there any way out of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Mockito in Kotlin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305217/is-it-possible-to-use-mockito-in-kotlin)

Comment: `createClassLoader` should be a method from a mock. It doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Sorry, it actually is. I'll change it to `foo.createClassLoader` to make it slightly clearer.

Comment: Ok. In Java, this would occur if the method was final or static. Or not a mock, or a partial mock with this method unmocked. How do you create the mock?

Comment: Yes @Henri, opening the mocked method in kotlin just worked great. Thanks (though error messages could be a little more clear ;)

Comment: What was the full stacktrace? Is it coming from EasyMock?