# ArgumentMatchers.any must not be null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, viewmodel

I am trying to test `ViewModel` to make sure livedata gets updated correctly. However when using `ArgumentMatchers.any()` it fails with `IllegalStateException` saying:

> ArgumentMatchers.any(mViewModel.CountSubscriber::class.java) must not
> be null

```
@Test
fun emitValueIfCountIs7() {
    doAnswer { invocation: InvocationOnMock ->
        val subscriber: mViewModel.CountSubscriber = invocation.getArgument(0)
        subscriber.onNext(7)
        null
    }.`when`(countUseCase).execute(
        ArgumentMatchers.any(mViewModel.CountSubscriber::class.java),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(Parameters::class.java)
    )
    
    // When
    mViewModel.getCount()
    
    // Verify
    assert(mViewModel.countResponse.value != null)
}
```

I am using Kotlin and have the following dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.23.4"
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0"
```

Here are my imports:

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.doAnswer
import io.reactivex.Observable
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock
```

Strange thing is that it used to work before, and I don't know what has happened that could affect this.

Comment: Can you post your imports? IIRC this can happen when using the non-kotlin matcher with kotlin code.

Comment: I updated the question with imports.

Comment: ArgumentMatchers.any(Class<T> type) always returns null no matter what object I am trying to match

Comment: You were right, I replaced org.mockito dependencies with com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2 ones and now it works !

Answer (score 95):

Getting matchers to work with Kotlin can be a problem.
If you have a method written in kotlin that does not take a nullable parameter, then we cannot match with it using Mockito.any().
This is because it can return void and this is not assignable to a non-nullable parameter.

If the method being matched is written in Java, then I think that it will work as all Java objects are implicitly nullable.

One possible solution would be to use a library like [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)
But you can solve this issue easily with a few lines of code yourself.

If you need typed any(type: Class)

```
private fun <T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any<T>(type)
```

OR

You can use this matcher  instead of Matchers.any() :

```
object MockitoHelper {
fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
   fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
}
```

and use `MockitoHelper.anyObject()` instead of `any()` in your kotlin tests.

You can find more information in this post: [Using  Mockito with Kotlin](http://derekwilson.net/blog/2018/08/23/mokito-kotlin)

There is a discussion about possible solutions in this post :
[Is it possible to use Mockito in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305217/is-it-possible-to-use-mockito-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation and these answers. The first typed class fn worked for me perfectly.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. The correct answer is you just need to use `import kotlin.any` instead of `import mockito.any` and it works.

Comment: This does not work (any more?) - it seems the kotlin compiler is now smart enough to not be confused by the unchecked cast of null to T

Comment: If your class have its own type then you are fucked. The only way would be using `mockito-kotlin`

Answer (score 65):

The correct solution is mentioned in the comment section of the question by @Ana Koridze. Yes, if you are using Koltin + mockitoKotlin. Make sure you are using the following import:

**1 - Using the Mockito-kotlin:**

`import org.mockito.kotlin.any` from Mockito-kotlin
instead of
`import org.mockito.Mockito.any`

```
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"
```

**2 - Or if you are using older mockito kotlin version original created by nhaarman before the intergation**

`import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.any` from nhaaram's Mockito-kotlin instead of `import org.mockito.Mockito.any`

```
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin2_version"
```

BTW, if you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA. the `any()` from mockitokotlin library should be *`italic`* by default style/color scheme.

---

Notice the `any()` at the end of line. This is from **mockitokotlin**

[image]

And here is the `any()` from **mockito**

[image]

Thanks @Sattar for the recommended edit.

Comment: the only thing worked for me. Thanks @Haomin

Comment: I had the same problem and then read your answer and checked my imports and now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

[mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) has added support for nullable args with `anyOrNull()`

```
        `when`(myMock.doesThis(any(), anyOrNull())).thenReturn(someObject)
```

Comment: note that you can use `whenever` which is an elegant alias to `when` (reserved keyword in Kotlin but not in Java), so you can avoid the slightly harder to read escaping.

Answer (score 6):

use [Mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin)

```
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"
```

this will use any that works for kotlin as this is a wrapper lib for Mockito but for kotlin

Answer (score 2):

**This is what worked for me,**

1. either replaced all generic `any()`s , with a specific anyTYPE(), i.e `anyInt()`, `anyList()` etc from core lib `org.mockito:mockito-core` and it fixes the (nullability)issue, it seems the specific definitions with type can handle null. this option does not require you to import any extra lib

**or**

2. if you really need to use the generic type `any()` , add this official Mckito extension lib https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin  and make sure you use the `any()` from this lib (by making sure your imports has this in it `import org.mockito.kotlin.any`)

I suggest to start using MockK lib  https://github.com/mockk/mockk instead of Mockito as it is a `Mock` library for `K`otlin = MockK)

however, if you feel lazy to switch right now or maybe dealing with legacy tests (as in my case :), this should fix your issue too.

Answer (score 2):

For me all solutions above were not enough - in addition to that I had to mark the called method as an 'open' method.
According to this:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null
The method is final and Mockito couldn't mock it so I had to add 'open'.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple wrapper function around Mockito's `any()` and got rid of the warning.

```
private fun <T> any() : T {
    return org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any()
}
```

I am still pretty green at Kotlin though, so I am not sure whether there may be some unwanted side effects. I put this answer out there in case it helps anyone or someone gives me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was specifying the type for any():

```
whenever(testedClass.testedMethod(any<SpecificType>()))
```