# How to solve EasyMock anyString() NullPointerException in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, easymock

I am using `EasyMock` with `Kotlin`. It works well but I bumped into a case when I need to mock 3rd party library call and I don't objectively need/have to verify the first param, so I want to use this construction:

```
EasyMock.expect(bucket.putObject(EasyMock.anyString(), message)).andReturn(PutObjectResult())
```

I am getting `null` pointer exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: anyString() must not be null

The reason why, underneath `EasyMock` has this implementation:

```
public static String anyString() {
    return (String)anyObject();
}

public static <T> T anyObject(Class<T> clazz) {
    reportMatcher(Any.ANY);
    return null;
}
```

I took a look at possible workarounds as in [Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305217/is-it-possible-to-use-mockito-in-kotlin) but nothing of this worked for me.

Is there a way to overcome this inconvenience with `EasyMock` and not getting `NullPointer` exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Kotlin expert. My first thought was that `bucket.putObject` isn't actually mocked. But it might be because `anyObject()` just returns null and the null validation in Kotlin causes that.

You could create your own matcher.

```
public static String anyString() {
    EasyMock.reportMatcher(Any.ANY);
    return "";
}
```

And see if it works.

Comment: I have no clue why it works, but nonetheless, it works perfectly. Thx!